# Comparing two different conditions for an ideal to correspond to a closed subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, homology-cohomology

Let $I$ be an ideal in the graded ring $S = A[x_0, \ldots, x_r]$.  In Exercise II.5.10(a), Hartshorne defines the *saturation* $\bar I$ of $I$ to be the set
$$\bar I = \{s \in S \mid \text{for all } i = 0, \ldots, r, \text{there exists an } n \text{ such that } x_i^n s \in I\}.$$
An ideal is *saturated* if $I = \bar I$.

Now let $\mathfrak{m} = (x_0, \ldots, x_r)$ be the irrelevant ideal in $S$ and define $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^0(I)$ by
$$H_{\mathfrak{m}}^0(I) = \bigcup_{n \geq 0} (0 :_I \mathfrak{m}^n)$$
where $(0:_I \mathfrak{m}^n) = \{a \in I \mid \mathfrak{m}^n a = 0\}$.

> **Question 1:** How do I show that, if $I$ is a saturated ideal of $S$, then $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^0(I) = 0$?

The two conditions in the question (namely "$I$ is saturated" and "$H_{\mathfrak{m}}^0(I) = 0$") are related to the bijection between saturated ideals of $S$ and closed subschemes of $\operatorname{Proj}(S)$.  The first one is in part (d) of the Hartshorne exercise quoted above, while the second is described [in this Mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70661/a-name-for-not-quite-saturated-graded-modules/70709#70709), or from Theorem A4.2 in Eisenbud's book on Commutative Algebra, or in Theorem 13.21 in "Twenty-four hours of local cohomology" by Iyengar *et al.* (which one can stumble across on-line).

I am also interested in a second, more difficult, result that we should be able to prove from the assumption that $I$ is saturated, namely

> **Question 2:** How does one show that, if $I$ is a saturated ideal of $S$, then $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^1(I) = 0$?

Here $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^1(I) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \operatorname{Ext}_R^i(R/\mathfrak{m}^n, I)$ is the first local cohomology group at $\mathfrak{m}$. It is known to be zero if and only if there exists an $I$-regular sequence in $\mathfrak{m}$ of length at least two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the ring $S$ (in Hartshorne) is a polynomial ring in $r+1$ indeterminates. Second, assume that $r\ge 1$.

Note that $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^0(S/I)=\overline{I}/I$. Then use the short exact sequence $$0\longrightarrow I \longrightarrow S \longrightarrow S/I\longrightarrow 0$$
which gives rise to a long exact sequence 
$$0\longrightarrow H_{\mathfrak{m}}^0(I) \longrightarrow H_{\mathfrak{m}}^0(S) \longrightarrow H_{\mathfrak{m}}^0(S/I)\longrightarrow H_{\mathfrak{m}}^1(I)\longrightarrow H_{\mathfrak{m}}^1(S)\longrightarrow \cdots $$
Since $\mathrm{depth}(S)\ge 2$, $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^0(S)=H_{\mathfrak{m}}^1(S)=0$ and this is it.